# Google Maps Flutter with Firestore: How to update geo query when user zooms out on Google Map

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-maps, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using `google_maps_flutter` with Firestore/GeoFlutterFire. I think my use case is pretty common.

1. User loads app with map centered to their location. Initial query is based on $X radius of their location (hard coded based on initial zoom).
2. User zooms out on the map

How can I update the query here to now display markers from the new bounding box of the map? Specifically:

1. How do I listen for changes in zoom
2. How do I use those changes to update a query? I guess I'd need to figure out the width/height of the map to determine the radius with something like [LatLngBounds](https://pub.dev/documentation/google_maps_flutter_platform_interface/2.2.4/google_maps_flutter_platform_interface/LatLngBounds-class.html) but I'm struggling take that data and convert it to a compatible geo query.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply listen to the changes of the map using `onCameraMove` & `onCameraIdle`.
`onCameraMove` will keep on updating while you are moving the map whereas `onCameraIdle` will be triggered once the map is stopped from moving.

For the radius calculation & geo query, you can add them under `onCameraIdle` callback.

To get the radius, you can simply achieve it by using `getVisibleRegion` function from *google_maps_flutter* package (to get the **LatLngBounds** of region that is visible on the map) & `distanceBetween` function from *geolocator* package to get the distance between the corners of visible map & divide by 2 to get the radius.

You can try to drag the map and utilize the circle drawn on map based on radius (refer to example code below) to check if the radius is working as expected. You should see the circle border just at the map corner once you start to drag the map & it will updated to the new radius once you release the drag on the map.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:geoflutterfire2/geoflutterfire2.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';

class MapScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const MapScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  MapState createState() => MapState();
}

class MapState extends State<MapPage> {
  final _controller = Completer<GoogleMapController>();
  double defaultZoomLevel = 16;
  CameraPosition? position;
  Set<Circle> circles = {};

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GoogleMap(
      circles: circles,
      mapType: MapType.normal,
      myLocationEnabled: true,
      myLocationButtonEnabled: true,
      initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
        target:
            LatLng(initialPosition!.latitude, initialPosition!.longitude),
        zoom: defaultZoomLevel,
      ),
      onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
        _controller.complete(controller);
      },
      onCameraMove: (cameraPosition) => position = cameraPosition,
      onCameraIdle: () async {
        if (position != null) {
          final GoogleMapController controller = await _controller.future;
          var vr = await controller.getVisibleRegion();
          // Option 1: Get distance between the corners of visible map & divide by 2
          double distanceInMeters = Geolocator.distanceBetween(
            vr.northeast.latitude,
            vr.northeast.longitude,
            vr.southwest.latitude,
            vr.southwest.longitude,
          );
          double radiusInMeters = distanceInMeters / 2;
          // Option 2: Get radius using `position` state updated onCameraMove
          // double radiusInMeters = Geolocator.distanceBetween(
          //   vr.northeast.latitude,
          //   vr.northeast.longitude,
          //   position!.target.latitude,
          //   position!.target.longitude,
          // );
          setState(() {
            circles = {
              Circle(
                circleId: const CircleId('id'),
                fillColor: const Color.fromARGB(80, 185, 105, 229),
                strokeColor: Colors.purple,
                strokeWidth: 1,
                center: LatLng(
                    position!.target.latitude, position!.target.longitude),
                radius: radiusInMeters,
              )
            };
          });

          final geo = GeoFlutterFire();
          GeoFirePoint center = geo.point(
            latitude: position!.target.latitude,
            longitude: position!.target.longitude,
          );
          // Add your query / call your function here
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

[image]